# Can I combine two decorators into a single one in Python?

Tags: python, decorator

Is there a way to combine two decorators into one new decorator in python?

I realize I can just apply multiple decorators to a function, but I was curious as to whether there's some simple way to combine two into a new one.

Comment: Related: [Merging python decorators with arguments into a single one](//stackoverflow.com/q/52517273)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

A bit more general:

```
def composed(*decs):
    def deco(f):
        for dec in reversed(decs):
            f = dec(f)
        return f
    return deco
```

Then

```
@composed(dec1, dec2)
def some(f):
    pass
```

is equivalent to

```
@dec1
@dec2
def some(f):
    pass
```

Comment: `return lambda x: reduce(lambda y, f: f(y), decs, x)`... well, after typing this I see the advantage of your code :)

Comment: Really useful, thank you.  I used this to create a new decorator:  
  
`@new_decorator = composed(dec1(some_params), dec2)`  
  
Which I'm using to have the decorator logic in one place (it's for user authorisation of a django view).  Your code will be a useful addition to the toolbox.  Cheers.

Comment: The order of execution of the decorators in the last example is `dec2` then `dec1`, i.e. `dec1(dec2(some(f)))`. `dec2` gets executed first.

Comment: @How to do the same for decorators that taking an args and kwargs?

Answer (score 38):

Yes. See the definition of a decorator, [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-decorated).

Something like this should work:

```
def multiple_decorators(func):
   return decorator1(decorator2(func))

@multiple_decorators
def foo(): pass
```

Comment: Thanks, and also a useful link.  I've opted for the answer with the more general solution.  Cheers.

Comment: I like how concise this solution is and have found it helpful in my project.

Comment: **Ditto.** Although the accepted answer _is_ admittedly awesome for the general case, this answer concisely exhibits one decorator deferring to multiple other decorators whose names are statically known at interpretation time. Since this is the usual case, this is great too! _Upvotes for all ensue._

Answer (score 16):

Decorators are just functions that take a function as input and return a new function. This:

```
@deco
def foo():
    ...
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
def foo():
    ...

foo = deco(foo)
```

In other words, the decorated function (`foo`) is passed as an argument to the decorator, and then `foo` is replaced with the return value of the decorator. Equipped with this knowledge, it's easy to write a decorator that combines two other decorators:

```
def merged_decorator(func):
    return decorator2(decorator1(func))

# now both of these function definitions are equivalent:

@decorator2
@decorator1
def foo():
    ...

@merged_decorator
def foo():
    ...
```

It gets a little trickier if the decorators accept arguments, like these two:

```
@deco_with_args2(bar='bar')
@deco_with_args1('baz')
def foo():
    ...
```

You might wonder how these decorators are even implemented. It's actually pretty simple: `deco_with_args1` and `deco_with_args2` are functions that return *another* function decorator. Decorators with arguments are essentially *decorator factories*. The equivalent of this:

```
@deco_with_args('baz')
def foo():
    ...
```

Is this:

```
def foo():
    ...

real_decorator = deco_with_args('baz')
foo = real_decorator(foo)
```

In order to make a decorator that accepts arguments and then applies two other decorators, we have to implement our own decorator factory:

```
def merged_decorator_with_args(bar, baz):
    # pass the arguments to the decorator factories and
    # obtain the actual decorators
    deco2 = deco_with_args2(bar=bar)
    deco1 = deco_with_args1(baz)

    # create a function decorator that applies the two
    # decorators we just created
    def real_decorator(func):
        return deco2(deco1(func))

    return real_decorator
```

This decorator can then be used like this:

```
@merged_decorator_with_args('bar', 'baz')
def foo():
    ...
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to repeat yourself too much in a test suite, you could do like this::

```
def apply_patches(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    @mock.patch('foo.settings.USE_FAKE_CONNECTION', False)
    @mock.patch('foo.settings.DATABASE_URI', 'li://foo')
    @mock.patch('foo.connection.api.Session.post', autospec=True)
    def _(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return _
```

now you can use that in your test suite instead of a crazy amount of decorators above each function::

```
def ChuckNorrisCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @apply_patches
    def test_chuck_pwns_none(self):
        self.assertTrue(None)
```

Answer (score 5):

If the decorators don't take additional arguments, you could use

```
def compose(f, g):
    return lambda x: f(g(x))

combined_decorator = compose(decorator1, decorator2)
```

Now

```
@combined_decorator
def f():
    pass
```

will be equivalent to

```
@decorator1
@decorator2
def f():
    pass
```

Comment: Isn't that "apply multiple decorators to a function"?

Comment: @delnan: Isn't that "some simple way to combine two [decorators] into a new one"? :)

Comment: Thank you.  One of the decorators takes params though so have gone with the other answer.

Answer (score 4):

And to extend @Jochen's answer:

```
import click


def composed(*decs):
    def deco(f):
        for dec in reversed(decs):
            f = dec(f)
        return f
    return deco


def click_multi(func):
    return composed(
        click.option('--xxx', is_flag=True, help='Some X help'),
        click.option('--zzz', is_flag=True, help='Some Z help')
    )(func)


@click_multi
def some_command(**args):
    pass
```

In this example you can compose a new decorator that contains multiple decorators.

Comment: or also `click_multi = composed(click.option('--xxx', is_flag=True, help='Some X help'),click.option('--zzz', is_flag=True, help='Some Z help'))`

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.9 we can use lambda expression as decorator.
Combine using lambdas in a single line

example:

```
@lambda func: (lambda func: (lambda *variable: func(*variable).upper()))  (lambda *variable: func(*variable) + ' World')
def say():
    return "Hello"

print(say())
```

The above function has two decorators.

`(lambda *variable: func(*variable) + ' World')` -- this decoration concatenates " World".

`lambda *variable: func(*variable).upper()` -- this decoration converts to upper case.