# How to group decorators in Python

Tags: python, flask, decorator, python-decorators

In Flask I'm using a set of decorators for each route, but the code is "ugly":

```
@app.route("/first")
@auth.login_required
@crossdomain(origin='*')
@nocache
def first_page:
    ....

@app.route("/second")
@auth.login_required
@crossdomain(origin='*')
@nocache
def second_page:
    ....
```

I would prefer to have a declaration that groups all of them with a single decorator:

```
@nice_decorator("/first")
def first_page:
    ....

@nice_decorator("/second")
def second_page:
    ....
```

I tried to follow the answer at [Can I combine two decorators into a single one in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409450/can-i-combine-two-decorators-into-a-single-one-in-python) but I cannot make it working:

```
def composed(*decs):
    def deco(f):
        for dec in reversed(decs):
            f = dec(f)
        return f
    return deco

def nice_decorator(route):
    composed(app.route(route),
             auth.login_required,
             crossdomain(origin="*"),
             nocache)

@nice_decorator("/first")
def first_page:
    ....
```

because of this error that I don't understand:

```
@nice_decorator("/first")
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Following one of the comments I defined it with another form that works but without the possibility to specify the route parameter:

```
new_decorator2 = composed(app.route("/first"),
                          auth.login_required,
                          crossdomain(origin="*"),
                          nocache)
```

Is it possible to define a single decorator with parameters?

Comment: `nice_decorator` does not returns nothing, so returns `None` and `None` is not callable. Add `return` before `composed(app.route...)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not defining the composition correctly. You need to change the definition of `nice_decorator` to something like this:

```
def nice_decorator(route):
    return composed(
        app.route(route),
        auth.login_required,
        crossdomain(origin="*"),
        nocache
    )
```

Your previous version never actually returned anything. Python isn't like Ruby or Lisp where the last expression is the return value.

Comment: Thak you to all of you!

I completely forgot the return.