# Merging Python decorators with arguments into a single one

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm using two different decorators from two different libraries. Lets say: `@decorator1(param1, param2)` and `@decorator2(param3, param4)`. That I often use in many functions as:

```
from moduleA import decorator1
from moduleB import decorator2

@decorator2(foo='param3', bar='param4')
@decorator1(name='param1', state='param2')
def myfunc(funcpar1, funcpar2):
    ...
```

Since it happens every time, I would like to create a *custom decorator* that handle both of them. Something like:

```
@mycustomdecorator(name='param1', state='param2',
                   foo='param3', bar='param4')
def myfunc(funcpar1, funcpar2):
    ...
```

How do I achieve that?

Comment: I don't think is the same, in post you mentioned the `@customdecorator` is receiving decorators. It will not be this case.

Comment: You can easily extend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5409491/1222951) to add parameters though.

Comment: can you please instead mark as duplicated, add the extension, since I'm not being able achieve that from that answer.

Comment: I don't think we should have two separate Q&As for merging decorators with and without arguments, so I'm going to post a more complete answer in the other question.

Comment: It will for sure help me that I will know that. But (IMHO) since that question already has a valid and accepted answer the new one (and also correct) will be hard to find.

Comment: I changed my mind. A good answer to your question probably wouldn't be a very good answer in the other question. Once you start explaining how decorators with arguments work and how you can merge them, the answer starts to go out of scope of the other question. I think we'll get more high-quality answers by leaving this question open.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I do agree with your point of view.

Comment: I have removed that paragraph from question. I was trying to make the change on question to avoid the "duplicity". But @brunodesthuilliers already changed the title. Anyway, what I meant is be able, in `customdecorator` to evaluate the parameters passed to the decorator, for example, check `if state == 'foostate': ...`. But I think that will be a natural consequence of the decorator constrution itself.

Comment: I don't think this duplicate flag is accurate. The other question does not ask about decorators with arguments, and the accepted answer would not be an answer to this question. Related ? Sure. Duplicate ? Nope.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would argue that you shouldn't - using the original names for the decorators gives much better readability.

However, if you really want to, you can do it like this:

```
import functools

from moduleA import decorator1
from moduleB import decorator2

def my_decorator(foo, bar, name, state):
    def inner(func):
        @decorator2(foo=foo, bar=bar)
        @decorator1(name=name, state=state)
        @functools.wraps(func)  # Not required, but generally considered good practice
        def newfunc(*args, **kwargs)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return newfunc
    return inner

@my_decorator(foo='param3', bar='param4', name='param1', state='param2')
def myfunc(funcpar1, funcpar2):
    ...
```

Based on comments though, here's an alternative method:

```
def my_decorator(foo, bar, name, state):
    def inner(func):
        # Please note that for the exact same result as in the other one, 
        # the order of decorators has to be reversed compared to normal decorating
        newfunc = decorator1(name=name, state=state)(func)
        newfunc = decorator2(foo=foo, bar=bar)(newfunc)
        # Note that functools.wraps shouldn't be required anymore, as the other decorators should do that themselves
        return newfunc
    return inner
```

To some, this might look simpler. However, people experienced with Python are used to decorators being applied with an @ - and even for that reason alone, I like my first option better. I know I'd take three times as long to read this code for the first time and understand what it does.

It's simple really - just write a decorator that returns another decorator which will have it's inner function decorated with the other two decorators ;)

It might also be a good idea to use functools.wraps, for the sake of good habits. It's standard library and helps a lot with debugging and interactive console use: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html

In general though, I'd say the one extra line of code is more than worth the clarity of using the decorators separately. You'll thank yourself when you read your own code in 3 more months.

Comment: You should be using [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) though. If you try `print(myfunc)` you'll get `<function my_decorator.<locals>.inner.<locals>.newfunc at 0x7f5ee7bbee18>` as output.

Comment: You're right, of course. I was a bit in doubt because this question indicates a certain inexperience with decorators, and I wasn't sure whether to add it. I'll make an edit about it, since it's better to learn it right the first time around, though.

Comment: While I usually agree that saving a line or two is not worth a loss in readability, if I had to apply the same two decorators to more than a couple functions I'd certainly wonder whether it's accidental or not, and in the last case refactor the whole thing to avoid repetitions.

Comment: If they're from two different libraries, it's not accidental. @Aran-Fey: Whoops. That'll teach me from trying to edit to fast.

Comment: @Jacco but then I'd start wondering why I didn't ever see the authors of the libraries in the same room at the same time.

Comment: I've worked myself with comparable situations - for example, combining PyQt signal/slots with State conditions on hardware controllers. Plenty duplicate decorators. That said, if you yourself have written either of the libraries, it might be worth incorporating a combined decorator. I know I would.

Comment: The `newfunc` in this answer can make it fail in some cases where chepner's answer (or using the two decorators explicitly) would have worked, particularly when one of the decorators needs to be applied to the original function.

Comment: @user2357112 anyfix to that?

Comment: @Lin: Apply the decorators to `func` directly.

Comment: "needs to be applied to the original function" - we're getting into really rare territory here, as this means that either the current or previous decorator is making a mistake - either the previous didn't use .wraps(), or the current doesn't check for it while doing it's function objects inspection. I'd call that a bug in the library. Regardless, the only thing a user can do about that is to move the offending decorator inwards, like you said. I fail to see how the compose would do that better - it still has only a single inner decorator. I'll edit in an alternative to directly apply to func.

Answer (score 4):

This is just simple function composition, where `decorator1` and `decorator2` are returning the functions you want to compose. The real work can be abstracted out into a function `compose`.

```
# In the special case of composing decorators, the lambda expression
# only needs to be defined with a single argument, like
#
#   lambda func: f(g(func))
#
# but I show a more general form.
def compose(f, g):     
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: f(g(*args, **kwargs))

def customdecorator(foo, bar, name, state):
    return compose(decorator2(foo=foo, bar=bar),
                   decorator1(name=name, state=state))
```

Answer (score 2):

Decorator is nothing more than a syntax sugar to the syntax like `func = decorator(func)`.

So, you can easily make your own decorator that does whatever you want with the following syntax:

```
def mycustomdecorator(foo, bar, name, state)
    def innerdecorator(func):
        func = decorator1(foo=foo, bar=bar)(func)
        func = decorator2(name=name, state=state)(func)
        return func
    return innerdecorator
```

After that, you should be able to use @mycustomdecorator with no hassle. Let me know if this works, I didn't test it but theoretically it should.

What's the magic there: first, we need to retrieve parameters for our decorators. This way, we are able to pass them on into nested function. Then, we are accepting our function as an argument, and the last, we are getting parameters for our function. We can nest our def-s as much as we need.

Comment: Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: Yes, I believe this is the way to preserve arguments for both foo() and mycustomdecorator(). Am I wrong?

Comment: The number of functions is fine; `decorator1` and `decorator2` are just being called in the wrong place. You want to apply them in `innerdecorator` *before* `wrapper` is defined, so that you aren't repeatedly calling them every time you call `func`.

Comment: (I should say "inefficient" rather than "wrong".)

Comment: Thanks chepner, you're totally right! I will remember this for future uses.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, could you please share an example on how can we not use extra nested function?

Comment: (The wrong part is that `wrapper` should *call*, not return, `func`.)

Comment: Your answer is really helpful, but I cannot predict what will happen if we use foo() there with arguments. Will they be correctly passed on to foo() or will it be called empty? I don't have REPL around atm, so I cannot tell. Can you?
*note: I forgot to call func() with arguments myself, my bad -- sorry*