# How to make sure all requests have permission?

Tags: python, flask, permissions, request

I have a flask application and I have created a custom decorator that checks some header information for permission on `controllers.py`.

`app.py`

```
app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

controllers.py

```
@route('/')
@custom_decorator
def get():
   pass


@route('/id')
def get_id():
   pass
```

On this case, see that I forgot to use my decorator on the second method. There is any way I can guarantee that If I forget my decorator a exception would be throw? In the case of a new dev in the team forget to use the decorator or something like that.
Is there any way I can do something with the request before it hit the controllers?

Comment: Why not make a decorator that merges functionality of `route` and `custom_decorator`?

Comment: The route one is from `Blueprint`. Not sure If I can override it behavior.  `from flask import Blueprint`.

Comment: Hi RonanFelipe, could I help you with my answer below?

Comment: I did use the `before_request()` method from flask. [Docs here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.Flask.before_request)

Answer (score 1):

You could merge the decorators and check if the name of some function is passed as an argument.

```
def composed(*decs):
    def deco(f):
        is_decorated = False
        for dec in decs:
            if 'custom_decorator' in dec.__qualname__.split('.'):
                is_decorated = True
            f = dec(f)
        if not is_decorated:
            raise SomeError
        return f
    return deco


@composed(blueprint.route('/'), custom_decorator)
def get():
   pass
```

For further reading you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409450/can-i-combine-two-decorators-into-a-single-one-in-python) about how to merge decorators in python.